# Example of non-consistency of M-estimators in case of pointwise converging criterion functions

Tags: convergence, asymptotics, consistency, m-estimation

When one wants to establish consistency of an M-estimator $\widehat{\theta}_n$, one typically requires uniform convergence of the criterion function $\theta \mapsto M_n(\theta)$. That is, one requires that
$$
\sup_{\theta \in \Theta} |M_n(\theta)- M(\theta)| \stackrel{P}{\to} 0.
$$
See for example Theorem 5.7 in "Asymptotic Statistics" by Van der Vaart (1998). A weaker condition is pointwise convergence of the criterion function which is given by
$$
M_n(\theta) \stackrel{P}{\to} M(\theta), \quad \text{for every } \theta \in \Theta.
$$
In case the criterion function is expressed as an $M_n(\theta) = \frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{i=1} m_{\theta}(X_i)$, one easily obtains pointwise convergence of the criterion function. Van der Vaart (1998) (pages 44-45) mentions that

"However, the (pointwise) convergence (5.6) is too weak to ensure the convergence of $\widehat{\theta}_n$. Because the value $\widehat{\theta}_n$ depends on the whole function $\theta \mapsto M_n(\theta)$, an appropriate form of "functional convergence" of $M_n$ to $M$ is needed, strengthening the pointwise convergence (5.6)."

I am struggling to find an example where such pointwise convergence of the criterion function is not sufficient for consistency (together with other suitable assumptions). Does anyone have any insights or intuition on this? I understand why uniform convergence is a stronger condition but I am failing to find an example where pointwise convergence is too weak.

Answer (score 2):

It *is* relatively hard to find a realistic one, because realistic M-estimators are better behaved than arbitrary M-estimators.

Here's an obviously artificial one. Take some starting $M$-estimator such as the sample median, maximising $M_n(\theta)=-\sum_i |x_i-\theta|$ and add a 1-unit wide smooth spike at $\theta=n$ to it. Choose the height of the spike so that the top of the spike is (with high probability) the maximum of the new objective function -- some multiple of $n$ will do. Call the new function $M^*_n(\theta)$

The resulting $M$-estimator is not consistent, because the estimator is the location of the spike, and so heads off to infinity. However, for any fixed $\theta$, or even any compact set of $\theta$, the spike is irrelevant to convergence because it's far outside that compact set for large enough $n$. So $M^*_n(\theta)$ will have the same limit as $M_n(\theta)$ at individual $n$ and uniformly on compact sets.

A milder problem occurs with the maximum likelihood estimator for a Cauchy distribution location.  We do not have uniform convergence over all of $\mathbb{R}$ and there are spurious local maxima even though the limiting function $M(\theta)$ has a unique maximum. In this example, though, the overall maximum is still consistent

Comment: Interesting, thanks for your reply! I did not know that this could be related to finding the MLE of a Cauchy distribution. The above answer by @D F gives an example where pointwise converges fails to give consistency, even under a compact set of $\theta$. It is indeed very artificial but I had never seen such an example, so I was just curious

Answer (score 1):

Consider a non-stochastic case: if you have a sequence of non-stochastic functions $f_n(x)$ that converges pointwise to some $f(x)$, the sequence of minimizers doesn't necessarily converge to a minimizer of $f(x)$, unless the convergence is uniform. Take as an example:
$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
2-2nx &\text{ if } 0 \le x < 1/n\\
2nx - 2&\text{ if } 1/n \le x < 2/n\\
\frac{n}{2-n}x+\frac{2-2n}{2-n}&\text{ if } 2/n < x < 1\\
x &\text{ if } 1 \le x \le 2\\
\end{cases}$$
it's easy to see that $f_n(x)$ converges pointwise to
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
-x+2 &\text{ if } 0 \le x < 1\\
x &\text{ if } 1 \le x \le 2\\
\end{cases}$$
whose unique minimizer on $[0, 2]$ is $x=1$ however the sequence of minimizers of $f_n(x)$ converges to 0.

For the stochastic case, take $M_n(\theta) = f_n(\theta) + \frac{Z}{n}$ with $Z \sim N(0, 1)$, pointwise it converges in probability to $M(\theta) = f(\theta)$ but minimizers do not converge to the minmizer of $f(\theta)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! The key seems to have some strict minimum in $f_n$  that disappears in the limit $f$ and such the argmin of $f_n$ does not converge to the argmin of $f$. I appreciate the effort!